# Golang equivalent of java servlet filter

Tags: http, go, servlet-filters

Does the Go language have an equivalent of the java servlet filter, such that you can have a single function of code that automatically gets added to all incoming http requests?  I'm also curious if it's possible to apply the filter to a URL pattern, ie, a subset of incoming requests based on URI.

What is the Golang way of doing this?

Comment: It is a wrapper func on every HandleFunc

Comment: Thank you - that pointed me enough in the right direction to get going.  Feel free to post that as an answer and I'll mark correct.

Comment: The Go community uses the term "middleware" for filters.  Search this site for "[go] middleware" to find many questions and answers on the topic.

Comment: Thank you Cerise for adding that.  People who have a java background will likely use the wrong terminology, like me, and land here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It a Middleware func which wrapps a HandleFunc

Something like it is descrived here
https://www.alexedwards.net/blog/making-and-using-middleware